# Android Kotlin DataStore with Protobufs - why can't I retrive my fields from the incoming flow?

Tags: android, kotlin, protocol-buffers, kotlin-flow, android-jetpack-datastore

I have read the [Android Documentation for DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#proto-schema) as well as the [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-proto-datastore#0) but I'm still unable to implement a simple collection of a boolean value in the Protobuf. My proto definition file is:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "com.namea.nameb.user_preferences";
option java_multiple_files = true;

message AppSettings {
  bool automatically_connect = 1;
}
```

The Serializer is:

```
object SettingsSerializer : Serializer<AppSettings> {
    override val defaultValue: AppSettings = AppSettings.getDefaultInstance()

    override suspend fun readFrom(input: InputStream): AppSettings {
        try {
            return AppSettings.parseFrom(input)
        } catch (exception: InvalidProtocolBufferException) {
            throw CorruptionException("Cannot read proto.", exception)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun writeTo(t: AppSettings, output: OutputStream) = t.writeTo(output)
}

val Context.settingsDataStore: DataStore<AppSettings> by dataStore(
    fileName = "settings.pb",
    serializer = SettingsSerializer
)
```

My Hilt module is below. I would like a MultiProcessDataStoreFactory so that I can access the DataStore in the UI thread and a background Service:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object UserPrefsModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideUserPrefs (@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) : DataStore<AppSettings> {
        return MultiProcessDataStoreFactory.create(
            serializer = SettingsSerializer,
            produceFile = { File("${appContext.cacheDir.path}/myapp.preferences_pb")},
            corruptionHandler = null,
            scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())
        )
    }
}
```

I simply want to retrieve the DataStore flow in a ViewModel (and eventually convert it into a StateFlow to be reflected in an output Compose component.

```
import com.namea.nameb.user_preferences.AppSettings
import com.namea.nameb.user_preferences.UserPrefs

@HiltViewModel
class PreferencesViewModel @Inject constructor(dataStore: DataStore<UserPrefs>): ViewModel() {
    val automaticConnectState: Flow<Boolean> = dataStore.data
        .catch { exception ->
            if (exception is IOException) {
                // Handle IO exception, e.g., handle network errors
            } else {
                throw exception
            }
        }
        .map { preferences -> preferences.AppSettings.automaticallyConnect ?= false }
}
```

However, `AppSettings` in the final `.map` line is unrecognized and highlighted red by AndroidStudio. I have made sure to build the project, the output `pb` file is generated, there are generated Java files for `AppSettings` and the `automaticallyConnect` field. I made sure to import them in the header of the ViewModel file. I've looked through many examples, but they are all usually doing something more complex with combining the DataStore output into other data structures. All I want is the simple boolean value to make a switch reflect the DataStore state! What am I doing wrong here?